# Add custom view dynamically to a recyclerview

Tags: android, listview, custom-view

I have to create a new custom view for each item added in a recycler view.

```
@Override
public ListViewAdapter.BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    BaseViewHolder viewHolder =new BaseViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(holder instanceof BaseViewHolder){
    circleAnimationViewClass =new CircleAnimationView(mContext);

    circleAnimationViewClass.addRadius(circleList.get(position).getRadius());
    circleAnimationViewClass.addSpeed(circleList.get(position).getSpeed());
    circleAnimationViewClass.addColor(circleList.get(position).getColor());
    if(getItemViewType(position) >-1){
        circleAnimationViewClass.onStart();
        holder.bindCircle(circleList.get(position));

    }
    }

}
public class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected Context mActivityContext;
    View circleAnimationView;
    TextView radiusTextView;
    TextView speedTextView;
    public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.circleAnimationView = (CircleAnimationView ) itemView.findViewById(R.id.animationView);
        this.radiusTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radiusText);
        this.speedTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.speedText);
        mActivityContext =itemView.getContext();
    }
    public void bindCircle(CircleProperties objCircle){
        circleAnimationViewClass.drawCanvas((CircleProperties)objCircle);
        circleAnimationViewClass.invalidate();
    }
}
```

This is my circleanimation class

```
 public void addRadius(int radius){
        circleRadius =radius;
    }
    public void addSpeed(int speed){
        circleSpeed=speed;
    }
    public void addColor(int color){
        circleColor= color;
    }
 public CircleAnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) 
{
        super(context, attributes);
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributes, R.styleable.CircleAnimationView);
        circleRadius = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CircleAnimationView_radius, 20);
        circleSpeed = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CircleAnimationView_speed, 100);
        circleColor =typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CircleAnimationView_circleColor, Color.BLACK);
        typedArray.recycle();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setColor(circleColor);
            if (i == 0) {
                startXPos = dpToPx(circleRadius);
                i = dpToPx(circleRadius);
                canvas.drawCircle(startXPos, dpToPx(40), dpToPx(circleRadius), paint);
                //canvas.drawCircle(dpToPx(200), dpToPx(200), dpToPx(30), paint);
            } else {
                startXPos =   startXPos >= (canvas.getWidth() - dpToPx(circleRadius)) ? dpToPx(circleRadius) : startXPos + dpToPx(circleSpeed / 16);

                canvas.drawCircle(startXPos, dpToPx(40), dpToPx(circleRadius), paint);

            }
            i++;
    }
```

Problem is when i am not getting the values of radius and speed in onDraw. I am using invalidate to call the ondraw of custom view. Main requiremnt is each time  a new item is added to recycler view, i need to create customview for that item and do a custum drwaing of item.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not able to identify animation view"?

Comment: I am unable add customview to a listitem. I want to do a custom canvas draw in each list item.
AnimationView is custom view which extends View.

Comment: Still not clear. What _exactly_ does "not able to identify animation view" mean? Are you getting compilation error? Like "Cannot resolve..."? Or is it crashing when you run it? If so, what's the Exception?

Comment: Its a compilation error it says animationView variable cannot be found.

Comment: Which one? `R.layout.animationView`, `R.id.animationView`, or another? The `R.id` looks to be correct, so are you sure the name of the XML layout file is `animationView.xml`?

Comment: AnimationView is my custom class which extends View.
And I am trying to use this view inside my listview.

Comment: Yes, I understand all of that. I'm asking very specific questions, here. I need specific answers to be able to help. You stated "it says animationView variable cannot be found." Exactly which occurrence of `animationView` in the posted code is causing the error? You're using `animationView` in at least three different ways: an `R.layout` resource, an `R.id` resource, and a Java variable. Exactly which one is showing the error?

Comment: R.layout.animationView is causing problem

Comment: OK, now what is the name of the XML file that contains the `<com.example.rckja.cs639springhw4.CircleAnimationView ...` element you show in the last block in your code? The last part of the `R.layout.` should be the name of that file (without the `.xml` extension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Recycler View or at least the view holder pattern correctly. And RecyclerView.Adapter.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {

private List<CircleProperties> properties;

ListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<CircleProperties> circleObjectList){
    mContext = context;
    circleList =circleObjectList;
}

@Override
public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if(viewType.equals(A_VIEW_TYPE) {
        return new CircleAViewHolder(mActivityContext, mInflater.inflate(CircleViewHolder.CIRCLE_A_VIEW_ID, parent, false));
    } else if(viewType.equals(B_VIEW_TYPE) {
        new CircleAViewHolder(mActivityContext, mInflater.inflate(CircleViewHolder.CIRCLE_B_VIEW_ID, parent, false));
    }       
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return properties.get(position).getType();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(properties.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return properties.size();
}
}
```

Then create view holders like this...

```
public class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

protected Context mActivityContext;
protected int mPosition;

public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
}

public BaseViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    mActivityContext = context;

}

public void bind(Object data){
}
}
```

And subclass that view holder like...

```
private class CircleAViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder{

    CircleAnimationView circleAnimationView;
    TextView radiusTextView;
    TextView speedTextView;

    ViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
        this.circleAnimationView = (CircleAnimationView ) itemView.findViewById(R.id.circle_animation_view);
        this.radiusTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radius_view);
        this.speedTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.speed_text_view);
    }

    public void bind(Object data){
        CircleProperties circleProp = (CircleProperties) data;
        radiusTextView.setText(circleProp.getRadius());
        speedTextView.setText(circleProp.getSpeed());
        animaitonView.drawCanvas(data);
        //TODO: Any other view setup using data.
    }
}
```

And a second view holder like...

```
private class CircleBViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder{

    CircleAnimationView animationView;
    TextView diameterTextView;
    TextView velocityTextView;

    ViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
        this.animationView = (CircleAnimationView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
        this.diameterTextView =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.diameter_view);
        this.velocityTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.velocity_text_view);
    }

    public void bind(Object data){
        CircleProperties circleProp = (CircleProperties) data;
        diameterTextView.setText(circleProp.getDiameter());
        velocityTextView.setText(circleProp.getVelocity());
        animaitonView.drawCanvas(data);
        //TODO: Any other view setup using data.
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one doubt why you have used two view holder.
Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: And in my requirement, I have to use CustomView that extends View and I need to draw canvas inside my view.

Comment: @varunbhargava I used 2 view holders and a base view holder to demonstrate use of different viewholders with different layouts. Technically you can even have multiple view holders that use different data types. For your requirement you basically create a view add it to viewholder. You could draw on it when view is created if you do not need data to draw. Or you can trigger your view to redraw using data passed in the bind() method call. I would direct you to android dev docs for details on this. https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: Inside my recycler view I am trying to create a new custom view and every time i want to invalidate.

Comment: I have updated y question Can you please look into the issue